# Applying CSS3 Transformations based on Window Width and Height

Tags: javascript, css, transformation

My web application is using some of the css3 transformations and I was wondering the best way to do these based on the window's width and height.  My css is doing multiple transformations and in a specific sequence, i.e the body does one, and an element on the body does a second after the transformation the body did. However, one of my transformations is hardcoded to move the element X pixels which I want to make dynamic based off the window's height and width.

Is there a way *without* javascript (I'd need to preserve the order of these transformations) to say something like:

```
.someClass {
    transform:translate(windowHeight /2, windowHeight);
}
```

Comment: I believe this is impossible with pure CSS. I afraid you might have to use Javascript

Comment: Is absolute positioning a possible alternative to `translate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform: translate` may not be your best bet.  I'd try `position: fixed` and use a window percentage value:

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use viewport based units. For instance:

```
transform: translate(50vw, 50vh);
```